# Условие JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Хочу написать условие:
Если время больше 10 и нажата кнопка `class="btn-order"`, вывести сообщение.
Как правильно написать второе условие (если нажата кнопка `class="btn-order"`)?

Пытаюсь так:

```
  var time = offset.getHours();
    var klik = $(".btn-order").click();
    if(time>10 && klik ){

    alert("успех")
    }
```

Comment: проверяйте время и выводите алерт в обработчике события клика на кнопку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn-order");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (time > 10) {
        alert("Успех");
    }
}, false);
```

Что происходит: навешиваем обработчик события `click` на элемент с классом `btn-order`, при клике проверяем время, и, если оно больше 10, выводим alert'ом "Успех".

Из комментариев - "как убрать обработчик после того, как он выполнился?".

Тут есть 2 основных варианта:

1. В качестве 3 аргумента `addEventListener` передать объект, содержащий `once: true`, например:

   ```
   btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
       if (time > 10) {
           alert("Успех");
     }
   }, {once: true});
   ```

   Минус - работает только в относительно современных браузерах.
2. Удалить обработчик события:

   ```
   btn.addEventListener("click", function checkTimeAndAlert() {
       if (time > 10) {
           alert("Успех");
       }

       this.removeEventListener("click", checkTimeAndAlert);
   }, false);
   ```

Comment: Все работает, как прервать нажатие? тоесть проверил условие, вывел сообщение, и клик чтобы не прошел

Comment: @gbrgbr Сейчас дополню.

Comment: попробовал оба варианта , клик всё равно срабатывает (

Comment: @gbrgbr вы производите эти операции по готовности DOM?

Comment: @gbrgbr потому что у меня оба работают, но скрипт подгружается с атрибутом `defer`.

Comment: @gbrgbr я проверил на CodePen - у меня тоже ни в одном из случаев не удаляется обработчик. Однако на локальной машине (в том же браузере) все работает прекрасно. С чем связано, пока не вижу.